# XPath: How do I return strings after each line break

Tags: python, html, xml, xpath

I am trying to parse an HTML file with python lxml's xpath method. Say I have the following element

```
<td class='some class'>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>foo
    <br>
    <br>bar
</td>
```

I hope to find every string following a `<br>` tag, **whether it's empty or not**. That is, I 'm expecting xpath to return

```
['', '', 'foo', '', 'bar']
```

Currently my code is

```
element.xpath('text()[preceding-sibling::br]')
```

which only yields a list of non-empty strings

```
['foo', 'bar']
```

Is there something obvious that I'm missing here? Could anyone please shed some light on how I can make it work?

edit: Sorry for a mistake in my question. There's **no newline** following each tag. So my question really amounts to

```
from lxml.html import fromstring
s = '<td class="some class"><br><br><br>foo<br><br>bar</td>'
element = fromstring(s)
print(element.xpath('text()[preceding-sibling::br]'))
```

the last line of which I want to modify such that my code yields

```
['', '', 'foo', '', 'bar']
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For empty tags no `text()` node is created when the document is parsed, so querying for them won't give any result.

The alternative would be to select all the `br` nodes and use `br.tail`, which contains the text content immediately following the node or `None` for an empty tag, e.g:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring
s = '<td class="some class"><br><br><br>foo<br><br>bar</td>'
element = fromstring(s)
print([e.tail or '' for e in element.xpath(".//br")])
```

This gives the expected output:

```
['', '', 'foo', '', 'bar']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from lxml import etree

html = '''
<td class='some class'>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>foo
    <br>
    <br>bar
</td>
'''
r = etree.HTML(html)
r.xpath('//td/text()')
```

out:

```
['\n    ', '\n    ', '\n    ', 'foo\n    ', '\n    ', 'bar\n']
```

It's not white space, it's newline.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I just realized that the newlines shouldn't be there (and edited my question), so in fact the string has consecutive line breaks. It seems that the code wouldn't work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
'//td[@class="some class"]//text()[preceding-sibling::br]'
```